# How to add js ad in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

My client send me an advertisment, 300x250, in ad folder 1 html file, 1 javascript file, and 1 images folder.

My question is how to put these files in my Wordpress website home page side panel.

I'm lot of time trying for put ad in wedgets area, also try with plugins.

Can anybody help me.

Kind regards

Comment: Do you have some kind of WordPress in Java? Or why do you tag this [tag:java]?

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to upload that files to a server and login to your wordpress admin panel and go to appearance  and widgets, and create a custom html widget on sidebar  and use html iframe tag to display the ad

for eg :

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/adpage" width="300" height="250"></iframe>
```

try